# rust structs with overlapping fields

Tags: rust

I have some structs with overlapping and unique fields. For now I handle this with enums of seperate structs like below. This makes it cumbersome to access the shared fields, and easy to continue working on the specific fields, after identifying the type:

```
pub struct MyStructA {
    pub a: u64,
    pub b: u64,
    pub c: u64,
    pub d: u64,
}
pub struct MyStructB {
    pub a: u64,
    pub b: u64,
    pub e: String,
    pub f: String,
}
pub enum MyStructEnum {
    Num(MyStructA),
    Str(MyStructB),
}

// This gets annoying with many shared fields
pub fn get_a(m: MyStructEnum) -> u64 {
    match m {
        MyStructEnum::Num(n) => n.a,
        MyStructEnum::Str(s) => s.a,
    }
}

// When we know m is MyStructB this is easy
pub fn work_on_b(m: MyStructB) {
    println!("{} {}", m.a, m.e)
```

Since I have many overlapping fields and more different types maintaing `get_a()`-like functions get tiring, and seems stupid assuming the struct are laid out like they would be in C.

So I could go for something like

```
pub struct NewStructA {
    pub c: u64,
    pub d: u64,
}
pub struct NewStructB {
    pub e: String,
    pub f: String,
}
pub enum NewStructEnum {
    Num(NewStructA),
    Str(NewStructB),
}

pub struct NewStruct {
    pub a: u64,
    pub b: u64,
    pub e: NewStructEnum,
}

// Now this is easy
pub fn new_get_a(n: NewStruct) -> u64 {
    n.a
}

// But now I can't access a after identifying the type B
pub fn work_on_b(m: NewStructB) {
    println!("{} {}", m.a, m.e)
}
```

Any ways to get the best of both worlds? In C this would be easy (and unsafe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go with a base struct, but *inside* the enum. That is:

```rust
pub struct NewStruct {
    pub a: u64,
    pub b: u64,
}
pub struct NewStructA {
    base: NewStruct,
    pub c: u64,
    pub d: u64,
}
pub struct NewStructB {
    base: NewStruct,
    pub e: String,
    pub f: String,
}
pub enum NewStructEnum {
    Num(NewStructA),
    Str(NewStructB),
}
```

Now you can define an accessor function for `base`:

```rust
pub fn base(v: &NewStructEnum) -> &NewStruct {
    match v {
        NewStructEnum::Num(NewStructA { base, .. }) => base,
        NewStructEnum::Str(NewStructB { base, .. }) => base,
    }
}
```

And accessing the common field is as easy as `base(&s).a`. You may need to create `base_mut()` too. Of course, you can still access fields when you have a reference to the concrete type.

This is not as good as with C, but is pretty good nonetheless.

Comment: Looks fine. Do you have any idea if the compiler is able to optimize all of this away? Since base is first in the struct, all match arms probably do the same. It's not important for my use case, but might be for others.

Comment: @mrtnlrsn The niche prevents optimizing. If you force no niche by `#[repr(C)]` to the enum, [it does optimize](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/a36xsGjcs).

Comment: Thanx. Everyone-else: more info on niche: https://rust-lang.github.io/unsafe-code-guidelines/glossary.html#niche